# split lightning card into 3 columns

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-experience, salesforcedx, salesforce1-app

I want to show account related records in 1 lightning card by side to side.
I tried to use lightning card, but not able to do that. Can someone help me an idea to show 3 objects related records side by side. is it possible with Lightning Card.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration of what you're trying to do? Any code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox. There is a drop-down of account records, When we select one of the account records, I want to show other custom objects information, which I already showed in lightning cards in the first 2 sections. And in the next section, it should show account-related(Contact,custom object1, custom Object 2) objects information in one section with side by side.

Comment: @AnjiReddy Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<lightning:layout>` to show information in upto 12 different columns.

[Lightning:layout Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/example)